# Getting Rid of Text Inside Parentheses

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm working on a data frame.
In the 'Date' column, for some reason some of the dates have a number in parentheses after the day of the month.

i.e. Apr 5 (2), 2010

which I would like to turn into: Apr 5, 2010

Is there a way to get rid of the space and the parentheses part for all rows in a column?

This is the only thing I've tried, but I'm very new to using regex so I have no idea how to fix it:

```
re.sub(" (.)", "", df['Date'])
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-06833d51a3a0> in <module>
      1 import re
----> 2 re.sub(" (.)", "", df['Date'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    193 
    194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses and periods both have special use in regexes, so if you want to match a paren, you need to explicitly escape it with `\(`.

A regex that might help you:

```
\(\d+\)
```

This will match parens with one or more digits inside.

If you also watch to match (and replace) the space before it, you can match whitespace with a `\s` escape sequence:

```
\s\(\d+\)
```

If you need to replace ANY string in parentheses (not just digits), you can replace the `\d+` with, for example, `.+` (periods will match ALL characters).

See this regex live at [regexr](https://regexr.com/4oh47).

Comment: Thank you! I am still getting an error though. I changed the code to ```re.sub(\s\(\d+\), "", df['Date'])```. The error that I get says "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character" with a little carrot pointed after the end of the code.

Comment: In python, you need to delimit a regex with quotes when you pass to a function such as `re.compile` (src documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)), (as you did in your initial question). in this case, `re.sub("\(\d+\)",...)`. Let me know if that solves it!